# MYSQL ORDER BY 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
----------------------------
| id | price | price_promo |
----------------------------
|  1 |    10 |           0 |
|  2 |     8 |           0 |
|  3 |    10 |           9 |
----------------------------
```

I have this following query:

```
$SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY price ASC"
```

All I want is to ignore the price column if `price_promo > 0` to have a order by real acquisition price, and to get this result:

```
----------------------------
| id | price | price_promo |
----------------------------
|  1 |    10 |           0 |
|  3 |    10 |           9 |
|  2 |     8 |           0 |
----------------------------
```

What query I need to do this?

Comment: there is no need to mention asc for ascending, because asc is taken by default

Comment: Do you want to customize your ORDER BY CLAUSE?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a ASC order by the real acquisition price. What query I need?

Comment: Which one is the real acquisition price?

Comment: If `price_promo` exist, the real acquisition price is `price_promo`. If `price_promo` doesn't exist, the real acquisition price is `price`. I want an ASC order by the real ascquisition price.

Comment: And by 'not exists' you mean ' = 0'? I would choose to make price_promo either `null` or the same as price, if there is no difference between the regular price and the promo price.

Comment: Do you want to intermingle price values from price and price_promo (using the latter where it is greater than zero)? Where would a record with price 7 and price_promo 11 be? Also you seem to be showing the highest value FIRST ie you want DESC rather than ASC

Comment: @user1274699 add the description of real ascquisition price in question itself it will help the user to answer it correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN price_promo = 0 THEN price
       WHEN price_promo IS NULL then price
       ELSE price_primo
    END
```

**EDITED after user comment:**
If you want descending order use this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
ORDER BY
    CASE 
       WHEN price_promo = 0 THEN price
       WHEN price_promo IS NULL then price
       ELSE price_primo
    END DESC
```

Comment: +1 This does solve the problem for the current data. However, if there is no acquisition price, I would choose to make it `NULL` instead of `0`, but that's an other issue.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I have another question: if I want DESC sorting how can I try?

Comment: @user1274699: take a look at my edited answer. At the end of the query I inserted DESC :)

Comment: You're right, I ignored the end of the query. You had a great vision with the query, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by multiple column with different order.

Try this....

SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY price DESC , price_promo ASC

Answer (score -2):

Please give more details? To get results you want (in your example), you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY price DESC , price_promo ASC
```